# Finding the maximum height of a tree and returning the sum of that path

Tags: python

```
   1
 2   3
        returns 1 + 3 = 4
```

I want to first find the maximum height of a tree and then find the sum of all its nodes.

If two path has the same height, only the path with larger sum will be return.

sorry for my bad examples... all i want to express is that a tree like above

should have the tree list like `[1, [2, None, None], [3, None, None]]` instead of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Please post what code you have so far so we can see what you may be doing incorrectly

Comment: Look up recursion. This is problem is very easy to solve with a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive function as recommended by Egg:

```
def sum_of_longest_branch(tree):
    """
    Parses a tree and returns a tuple containing (depth, sum) of deepest branch.
    """
    # stop conditions on leave nodes (can be single [node] or None)
    if 1 == len(tree):
        return 1, tree[0]
    elif None == tree:
        return 1, 0
    # splitting the branches
    else:
        # calling the function recursively on all branches branching from current node
        branches_sums = [sum_of_longest_branch(branch) for branch in tree[1:]]
        # extracting the currently deepest branch
        branch, sum = sorted(branches_sums, reverse=True)[0]
        # add own node value and one depth before returning
        return branch + 1, sum + tree[0]
```

Example:

```
tree = [1, [2, [4]], [3, [0]]]
depth, sum = sum_of_longest_branch(tree)
print depth, sum
```

Gives:

```
3, 7
```

Sorry if it's quick & dirty, but it works. The problem is actually not that trivial, especially for a beginner to programming / python. I hope its understandable.

Edit: Now checks first for depth and secondarily for the sum.

Comment: What's the worst case complexity of your algorithm? Could this end up traversing the entire tree to figure out the answer?

Comment: the code for me its quite hard to understand.. but i notice that i have my tree form totally messed up. It should be [1,2,3] for 1 being root 2 - left child 3 - right child and a tree [1,None,None ]  means it only has the root 1 with no children

Comment: @ChristopherPerry: Yes, it does, in _all_ cases :) And I just noticed that I do not check for the largest sum as well as the greatest depth (changed in the edit). The request was for an easy method, not the fastest.

Comment: @user3417260: That makes no sense... the whole tree must somehow be contained in a single data structure (e.g. a list). Please edit and reformulate your question.

Comment: @loli: sorry for my bad examples... all i want to express is that a tree like               1 
                      /   \
                     2     3

should have the tree like `[1, [2, None, None], [3, None, None]]` instead of `[1,2,3]`

Comment: For that, simply replacing the stop-condition `if 1 == len(tree):` with `if None == tree:`should do the trick. And `return 1, tree[0]` has to be replaced with `return 1, 0`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tree_height(tree):
    if (isinstance(tree, list)):
        tree = tree[1:]
        if (tree):
            return (1 + max([tree_height(x) for x in tree]))
    return 0

def tree_sum(tree):
    if tree and (isinstance(tree, list)):
        return tree[0] + sum([tree_sum(x) for x in tree[1:]])
    return (tree or 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these values weights? Is the tree sorted in any way (is there a particular order to the tree)?

If so, maybe you can do a modified version of [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) where you take the longest distance at each junction instead of the shortest, and instead of a min-priority queue use a stack so you traverse depth first instead of breadth first.

EDIT:

Now that I think about it, perhaps using a max-priority queue would work better. I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish. What I think you are asking for is the path with the largest sum, which doesn't necessarily mean it will be the branch with the most nodes. The path with the most nodes, given that each node appears to have a weight, seems meaningless because there could be shorter paths with greater weight.

Comment: Seems a bit unnecessary.  Whether they are weights or not, it's a tree, wouldn't a simple traversal be simpler?

Comment: You should just need to go through the tree in-order and remember the longest path you have taken so far.

Comment: We need more info, if the tree is sorted we can make a choice at each level of the search and guarantee the path with the largest sum (which is what I think he wants). Also, what is a "simple" traversal? There are different ways to traverse a tree, all of each for a specific purpose.

Comment: Any depth-first traversal would seem the simplest approach to me.

Comment: Simplest isn't always most performant. If there is order to the tree you can make an assumption about the sum given past/present information at any given point of the search and avoid searching parts of the tree that you don't need to. DFS on the entire tree is not performant.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not quite understanding what is meant by a *modified* Djikstra implementation. Djikstra's shortest path algorithm is generally stated as an O(n^2) algorithm, where tree traversal is a an O(n) operation. Further, Djikstra's algorithm can't calculate longest paths, which would get into the same problem as a shortest path for a graph allowing negative weights.  Also, Djikstra's algorithm provides the shortest path between two known vertexes, whereas this is asking for the longest path from the root vertex to *any arbitrary leaf*.  I just don't think I get what you are proposing.

Comment: @femtoRgon I think I might have misinterpreted the question, the way it was written the tree appears to be sorted, and I was thinking it was asking for the path with the greatest sum, not the greatest sum of the longest path, which is a different problem. My bad. :/